# Large White Gap Above Header in Chrome

Tags: html, css

The developer who was working on this website left our company before this site was complete. Now that he is gone, I'm trying to clean up the code a bit and get rid of some bugs - however, the code is pretty chaotic at some points.

[Here is a screenshot of the problem](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/6004/screenshot20121113at105.png) (Chrome on left, Firefox on right):

[image]

[The website in question](http://goo.gl/KqOlf)

How do I remove this gap?

Comment: looks like you have some validation errors you should clean up for one: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://174.132.149.157/~hslprope/

Comment: Such a discrepancy between modern browsers on common layout/positioning stuff usually indicates some malformed code somewhere.  You should go through the code, and clean it up.

Comment: ^^True. Before you start fiddling with the CSS to try and make it show properly on Chrome, make sure the it's all valid and then, if the problem still occurs, start fiddling around with the code.#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put an absolute position on the "Find a Property" module and placed a relative position on the container holding it. Seems to work well in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE (all versions).

So I changed the positioning on the module to Relative and it seems to be displaying correctly in all browsers.

It's not the best solution, but it will do until I have some time to re-code it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;
position: absolute;
left: 450px;
```

Which *should* stop it taking up any space on the page, without being wildly out to the left (as in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13366378/962144))

Comment: I don't think `float: left` will have any effect here...

Comment: Oh you're right - It's left over from playing around in Web Inspector in Chrome. I'll update it.

Comment: Using `left: 450px` makes the box go all over the place on different screen widths.

Comment: I know, I was relying on him to find out a suitable value for that. Otherwise, you'd have to rearrange the markup and put it inside another container.

Comment: It's not going to work with an absolute position and left value in general, no matter what value it is. Bit of a tough one this is. Should be fine with a relative position and a value but something within the css doesn't like that.

Comment: I put an absolute position on the "Find a Property" module and placed a relative position on the container holding it. Seems to work well in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE (all versions).